# iPhone Setting size ratio on images

Tags: iphone

I'm making a slide show where the images are different sizes.  Right now the images get stretched out to fit into the image vue.  Is there a way to get the dim of the images, then re=size the imagevue? or maybe another way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to set the UIViewContentMode on your UIImageView(s).

Like this: `myImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit`

Look at the docs to determine which one to use (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can set the image view's `contentMode` to `UIViewContentModeAspectFit` so that the image gets resized but retaining its aspect ratio.

You can see [UIView Class Reference - UIViewContentMode](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIViewContentMode) for explanation.